# Recursive error occurs when using query dsl

Tags: querydsl

entity

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "voc_category"
)
data class VocCategoryEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cate_seq", nullable = false)
    var cateSeq: Long? = null,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_cate_seq")
    var parentCategory: VocCategoryEntity? = null,

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "parentCategory",
        targetEntity = VocCategoryEntity::class,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    var childrenCategory: List<VocCategoryEntity>? = ArrayList()
}
```

repository

```
val voc = query
        .selectFrom(vocCategoryEntity)
        .innerJoin(vocCategoryEntity.childrenCategory)
        .fetchJoin()
        .fetch()
```

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

There is an error, is there a solution?

I've changed both cascade and entry, but it doesn't work properly